# jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in other <select>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to attempt to disable an option if it is selected in any of the selects

So for example if name="select1" has selected option "Test 2", then I want "Test 2" to be disabled in both select statements... and if something else gets checked that it re-enables the previous option.

I have written a sample script here to which I thought would get me 'close'... but it's put me far off base here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("select").change(function() {
  $("select").find("option:selected").attr('disabled', true);
 });
});
</script>

<select name="select1">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If the user selects "Test 2", you want that option to become disabled in both boxes? Then what should become selected?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Sorry your right, if it is selected in 1, disable it in others.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/

```
$('select').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });

});
```

---

You may prefer this version of the code:

```
$('select').change(function() {

    $(this)
        .siblings('select')
        .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
        .attr('disabled', true)
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/2/

Note that this second version is an one-liner (one line of code) but I formatted it to be more readable. I like this second version better.

---

Also, note that my code assumes that those two SELECT boxes are DOM sibling elements. If that's not your case, then this code - `$(this).siblings('select')` - will not work for you, and you will have to use jQuery's traversal methods to jump to the other SELECT box.

In the worst-case scenario - when the SELECT boxes are far apart in the DOM tree, and traversing would not be efficient - you can just assign ID attributes to them and use this code to select the other box:

```
$('#select1, #select2').not(this)
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/3/

Comment: I've up-voted this as the code style is nice.  Though a warning on the use of `.siblings()` as the example code just shows the `<select>` elements in isolation, not their actual location within the DOM, they could potentially not be siblings.

Comment: @Orbling Yes, good point. I've updated my answer to address this.

Comment: If you are looking at supporting this feature with `multiple="multiple"` this http://jsfiddle.net/unpzveLo/ can help. (it's no longer one line of code)

Comment: If you have an `<option selected disabled hidden>Please select...</option>` at the beginning of your `<select>`, you can change `.siblings().removeAttr('disabled');` to `.siblings('[value]').removeAttr('disabled');`. This way, the first "unselectable" option will be ignored

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("select").change(function() {   
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
  }); 
});
```

In case you want to enable a previously disabled option (when the value is unselected from other combo), use this enchanced version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var prevVal = $this.data("prev");
        var otherSelects = $("select").not(this);
        otherSelects.find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
        if (prevVal) {
            otherSelects.find("option[value=" + prevVal + "]").attr('disabled', false);
        }

        $this.data("prev", $this.val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that within the `change()` routine, you are looking at all of the selects, rather than the one that has changed and disabling all of the selected entries.  You need to find the value of the selected entry in question and disable that in *other* selects, not the current one.

Something like this may be of use [untested]:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").each(function(cSelect) {
    $(this).data('stored-value', $(this).val());
  });

  $("select").change(function() {
    var cSelected = $(this).val();
    var cPrevious = $(this).data('stored-value');
    $(this).data('stored-value', cSelected);

    var otherSelects = $("select").not(this);

    otherSelects.find('option[value=' + cPrevious + ']').removeAttr('disabled');
    otherSelects.find('option[value=' + cSelected + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

The `stored-value` bit is so you know which options to enable in other `<select>` fields.

Comment: I need help...i have 2 separate divs with 2 select each....how can i apply this to work....i already tried something in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/2095/ but it works only for the first group of selects

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than 2 select :

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('select').each(function(i, elt) {
        $('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+$(elt).val()+'"]').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```