# jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in multiple <select> boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a question similar to the one asked here: [jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in other <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610652/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-other-select)

But, mine varies in that there will be more than two select boxes.  In the answer provided, when an option is selected, it is set to disabled in the other select boxes (which I want to happen), but I don't want any other options selected in a different select box to have disabled removed.

Does that make sense?

Example html:

```
<div>
<select name="homepage_select_first">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select name="homepage_select_second">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select name="homepage_select_third">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>    
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('select[name*="homepage_select"]').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
    $('select[name*="homepage_select"]').children('option').each(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true)//.siblings().removeAttr('disabled');  

        }
    });

});
```

Commenting out `.siblings().removeAttr('disabled')` simply never removes the disabled attribute...but, I want to remove it ONLY if it isn't selected in any one of the select boxes.

Basically, I only want an option to be selected in one of the selects at a time. I would think that if I could only `.removeAttr('disabled')` on the item that was just changed, I think that would work.  But, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this straight - all of your select elements will start off without the disabled attribute, then once one is selected, it will have the disabled attribute added to it. If another select element is then selected, the previous element should have the disabled attribute removed, and the current one would then become disabled? Do I have that right?

Comment: Not quite - let's say homepage_select_first has option value 1 selected and homepage_select_second has option value 3 selected - both of those should be disabled in homepage_select_third.  But, if I change my selection in homepage_select_first, it should be reflected in the other two, but value three should remain disabled because it's selected in homepage_select_second.

Comment: Alright, so the goal is to prevent duplicate options between the three select elements from becoming selected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it. Basically does what your comments ask - ensures that all 3 selects have unique selections. Once a selection is made in 1 selext box that option is no longer available in the others.

```
$('select[name*="homepage_select"]').change(function(){


    // start by setting everything to enabled
    $('select[name*="homepage_select"] option').attr('disabled',false);

    // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
    $('select[name*="homepage_select"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('select[name*="homepage_select"]').not($this).find('option').each(function(){
           if($(this).attr('value') == $this.val())
               $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        });
    });

});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QKy4Y/

Comment: I tried to come up with something for a while, but it didn't work quite right. Your solution works great.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work: if you select "test" in the first select you can't reset it

Comment: (By resetting i mean selectin "no match" another time)

Comment: @Nicola - I see what you mean, but mine treats all options as equal. Therefore the "no match" can only be selected once. I see yours has a special case for `value != ""`. Perhaps thats what the OP wants, i dont know.

Comment: @Jamiec - now i understand! :) MAybe you are right i didn't think of it! :)

Comment: That works great!  And, you're right, I do want 'no match' to be selectable at all times.  But, your code got me off in the right direction.  Here's what I added so that 'No Match' could always be selected: http://jsfiddle.net/dZR6r/

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
<div>
    <select id='1' name="homepage_select_first">
        <option value=''>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id='2' name="homepage_select_second">
        <option value=''>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select id='3' name="homepage_select_third">
        <option value=''>No Match</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>    
</div>
$('select[name*="homepage_select"]').change(function() {
    var selectedOptions = $('select option:selected');
    $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
    selectedOptions.each(function() {
        var value = this.value;
        if (value != ''){           
        var id = $(this).parent('select').attr('id');
        var options = $('select:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');
        options.attr('disabled', 'true');
        }
    });


});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8AcN4/2/