# Allow user to select option only once

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4 .I have multiple select boxes with same option.Basically they are dynamically generated select boxes.I want one 
            option should selected only once.I tried disable option once it selected.But it wont be appropriate because if user want to change selection 
            its not possible.

How it can be done?

> Edited

```
$('.select_user').change(function (){
     $(this).find('option:selected').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Here select_user is the class of selectboxes

Comment: Please, show what you've tried.

Comment: @Cloud i have edited

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309730/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-multiple-select-boxes