# Remove dropdown after it is selected in each table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table, containing two rows.

In each td, my content is a select dropdown.

The image below has it all.

[image: Select dropdown in each td]

What I have to achieve is that I need to select an option from drop down of one td and remove that option from other tds.

Say for example I select a value abc from dropdown 1 in first td.

Then, value abc must be removed from all the other dropdowns in all tds.

Here is some code :

HTML :

```
<select id="sameidforalltds"><option> abc </option><option> def </option>/select>
```

And the jQuery :

```
var getAllSelect = $("#Tablelayout_2").find('select');
            var selectDropdownValue = $(this).find($("option:selected").val());
            if(!($(getAllSelect).has(selectDropdownValue)))
            {
                $('select').remove(selectDropdownValue);
            }
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

Kindly advice where I am wrong.

Comment: but what will happen if you have only 2 options at the start and you have 3 tds. Then first 2 options will get used by first 2 td and last td's select will not have any option to select from.

Comment: First problem I can see is `selectDropdownValue` is returning an array `[]` You should debug your source code and you develop it.

Comment: are there same values in all dropdowns?

Comment: yes @Subho there are same values in all  dropdowns and the id's of all dropdowns are the same

Comment: hi @AshishBahl , but same id multiple time itself causing an error. You can add class instead of id. Create a datasource, like a json file or an array with the options. Then get the onChange function of one drop down and populate the others from the same datasource. You can add the if condition while creating the dropdowns and reject the selected value.

Comment: @AshishBahl rather than removing them why not disable them? I did start writing something for this but then I come to realise this solution no doubt already exists. Reason for my suggestion to disable them is because, what if the client changes their mind on which value they want in that select? Well you can't change them because those options no longer exist so by disabling/enabling them you give the client the option of changing their minds/choice of value..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309730/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-multiple-select-boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

**Html**

```
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$('.ddl').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()!="0") {  
       $('select[class="ddl"]').not($(this)).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
   }
})
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c4vkg5c4/)

This will help you.

Comment: you need only hide that option? @Subho

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain vanilla solution, just in case anybody is interested:

**DEMO**:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47uvyro4/)

**HTML**

```
<table id='TableLayout_2'>
<tr>
  <td><select onchange='change(this, 0)'><option>abc</option><option>def</option><option>ghi</option></select></td>
  <td><select onchange='change(this, 1)'><option>abc</option><option>def</option><option>ghi</option></select></td>
  <td><select onchange='change(this, 2)'><option>abc</option><option>def</option><option>ghi</option></select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function change(current, index) {
  var value = current.value;

  var selects = document.getElementById('TableLayout_2').getElementsByTagName('SELECT');
  for (var i = 0 ; i < selects.length ; i++){
    if (i === index)
      continue; // skip current select

    var toRemove = -1; 
    for (var j = 0 ;j < selects[i].options.length ; j++) {
      var text = selects[i].options[j].text;
      if (text == value)
        toRemove = j;

    }
    if (toRemove > -1)
      selects[i].removeChild(selects[i][toRemove]);
  }
}
```