# jquery - do something when not select an option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My question is similar to this :
[jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in multiple <select> boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309730/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-multiple-select-boxes)

and this :
[jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in other <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610652/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-other-select)

but different.

I have this html form:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form_letter">
<label for="letter">Letter</label><br>
<select multiple="multiple" name="letter[]" id="letter">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<label for="list_of_a">List of A</label><br>
<select multiple="multiple" name="list_of_a[]" id="list_of_a">
    <option value="A1">A1</option>
    <option value="A2">A2</option>
    <option value="A3">A3</option>
    <option value="A4">A4</option>
</select>

<label for="list_of_b">List of B</label><br>
<select multiple="multiple" name="list_of_b[]" id="list_of_b">
    <option value="B1">B1</option>
    <option value="B2">B2</option>
    <option value="B3">B3</option>
    <option value="B4">B4</option>
</select>

<label for="list_of_c">List of C</label><br>
<select multiple="multiple" name="list_of_c[]" id="list_of_c">
    <option value="C1">C1</option>
    <option value="C2">C2</option>
    <option value="C3">C3</option>
    <option value="C4">C4</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>​
```

what i want to achieve is when an `option` of `select[name="letter[]"]` is not selected and then click the `submit` button, the `select` list of corresponding letter is `null` or `empty`.

the scenarios:
1. If `option` A of `select[name="letter[]"]` is not selected, then click the `submit` button, the `select[name="list_of_a[]"]` will be `empty` or `null` even if one of its options selected.
2. The same thing goes for B and C.
3. If none of the `letter`'s options selected, then `list_of_a`, `list_of_b`, and `list_of_c` are empty.

this is my js :

```
$("form[name='form_letter']").on("submit", function(e) {
    if ($("select[name='letter[]']").find("option:not(:selected)").val() == "A") {
        $("select[name='list_of_a[]']").val("");
    };

    if ($("select[name='letter[]']").find("option:not(:selected)").val() == "B") {
        $("select[name='list_of_b[]']").val("");
    };

    if ($("select[name='letter[]']").find("option:not(:selected)").val() == "C") {
    $("select[name='list_of_c[]']").val("");
    };

alert("A = " + $("select[name='list_of_a[]']").val() + " and B = " + $("select[name='list_of_b[]']").val() + " and C = " + $("select[name='list_of_c[]']").val());

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​
```

I have been working on it here http://jsfiddle.net/VPhPv/21/ 
but got stuck.
help me please.

Comment: Why aren't you finding the elements by `id`?

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/VPhPv/26/

Comment: yes @Jack, I should do that.
its not working properly if I select more than 1 options for `#letter`, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment was close. I figured I'd put on the final touches I think you need.

It is important to remember that a multiple option select box like this will return an `array` of values.

http://jsfiddle.net/VPhPv/31/

Corresponding code.

```
var $form = $('#myForm'),
    $letterlist = $('#letter'),
    $listA = $('#list_of_a'),
    $listB = $('#list_of_b'),
    $listC = $('#list_of_c');

$form.on("submit", function(e) {
    var a, b, c;

    if ($letterlist.val().indexOf("A") != -1) {
        a = $listA.val();
    };

    if ($letterlist.val().indexOf("B") != -1) {
        b = $listB.val();
    };

    if ($letterlist.val().indexOf("C") != -1) {
        c = $listC.val();
    };

    alert("A = " + a + ", B = " + b + " and C = " + c);

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: great! thanks @Jack
but i wonder what happen if the `undefined` value is being passed via HTTP POST?

Comment: @rori You can either check your `a,b,c` values again before you post, or you can validate your values on the server before you take any action on them.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are comparing single values as equal to against the `:not` of `:selected`. You are never entering into a true condition on your if comparisons as you have written them. If you put alerts (or use a debugger) into them, you will see this.

Instead you need to do a not equals compare against the value that *is* selected:

`:selected").val() !=`

[appropriate solution jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmQue/)

You could also neaten things up a bit by using element ids in your selectors.