# Select option Hidden if selected in other select in array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

For example

if `id="select[1]"` selected `value=1`

`id 2-5` can't select `value=1`

```
<?php for($i= 0;$i<5;$i++){ ?>
    <select id="select[]" name="select[]">
        <option hidden selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could you describe your question more clearly.

Comment: Same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610652/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-other-select but is in array

Comment: Question is unclear. Please elaborate your problem and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to mantain states of each select, or something similar, my approach would be to reead and disable corresponding options when you change an selection

```
$('select').change(function() {

    // First we enable all options.
    $('select option:not(:first)').prop('disabled',false);

    // Then we take each selected value and disable that option in all selects.
    $('select').filter(function() { return $(this).val() != 'Please Select' }).each(function() {
        $('select').not(this).find('option[value='+this.value+']').prop('disabled',true);
    });

});
```

Here you have a working fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/26ce42od/

A piece of advice, I don't think you can use arrays with the `id` and is probably going to give you problems. You better set a unique id for each select, that is pretty easy in your case...

```
<?php for ($i= 0; $i<5; $i++) { ?>
    <select id="select<?=$i?>" name="select[]">
        <option hidden selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. With this code, when you select an option in one select, that option is disabled in the rest of the selects... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/26ce42od/
Is not that what you want?

Comment: **Sorry,My English isn’t that well.**      example, if in id="select[1]" you select form value="1" and change  id="select[1]" to value="2" and change again id="select[1]" to value="3" next I want select  id="select[2]" to value="2" I cann't sclect value="2" beause value="2"  disable

Comment: $(this).find('option[value='+selValue+']').prop('disabled',true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');       is not working

Comment: I think I get it now. You want to reset the disabled values each time you select one element, right? I've edited the answer. Is know what you want?