# Disable and/or Enable Select Option when selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie in jQuery. I have two identical SELECT elements *SelectA* and *SelectB*. I would like to disable the option which is identical by value in SelectB when selected in SelectA and vise-versa. At the same time, I would like to enable the disabled options when the selections from either Select Element changes.

This is **SelectA**

```
 <select name="SelectA" class="select form-control" id="id_SelectA">
  <option value="College GWA">College GWA</option>
  <option value="Field Study">Field Study</option>
  <option value="Compre">Compre</option>
  <option value="Batch">Batch</option>
  <option value="Age">Age</option>
  <option value="Entry Year">Entry Year</option>
  <option value="High School GWA">High School GWA</option>
 </select>
```

This is **SelectB**

```
 <select name="SelectB" class="select form-control" id="id_SelectB">
  <option value="College GWA">College GWA</option>
  <option value="Field Study">Field Study</option>
  <option value="Compre">Compre</option>
  <option value="Batch">Batch</option>
  <option value="Age">Age</option>
  <option value="Entry Year">Entry Year</option>
  <option value="High School GWA">High School GWA</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery <select> option disabled if selected in other <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610652/jquery-select-option-disabled-if-selected-in-other-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the element with jquery and get its value. Then, see if it matches any of the values of the options in the other select element and set the 'disabled' field to false.

```
$('#id_SelectA').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#id_SelectB option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == value) {
            $(this).disabled = true;
            break;
        }
    });
});
```